# Hover option in Google chrome devtools not working

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Im facing a problem with google chrome devtools....
I used to hover on a variables and it would pop up a tooltip telling me the value and other info, also on a function it would pop a link to click and it will take me to the definition location of that function, but all that is gone now and not working anymore...
Now i just see my cursor blinking when i hover over the variables... and im coding using VS Code i dont know if that might also be a problem, but i think i got this problem from a recent chrome update.

[image]

Comment: Apparently you've highlighted (selected) `displayResult` which is why it's displayed on the second picture. Remove the selection by clicking anywhere.

Comment: Otherwise it could be https://crbug.com/1015367 fixed in Chrome 80 so I guess you'll have to switch to Canary until the stable channel gets an update.

Comment: @wOxxOm im just with my mouse pointer over that function, its not highlighted